# AVCodecContext settings for H264 (1080i)

Tags: video-capture, video-encoding, libavcodec, x264

I'm trying to configure x264 for 1080i capturing. Most of these settings below are found in different examples. However, compiled together they don't work. ffmpeg API reports no error, but `avcodec_encode_video()` always returns zero.

Some of the numbers are strange to me... for example, `gop_size`. Isn't 250 too high?

Event you can't offer the final answer, I'm still interested in any kind of comment on this subject.

```
pCodecContext->codec_type              = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
pCodecContext->codec_id                = CODEC_ID_H264;

pCodecContext->coder_type              = FF_CODER_TYPE_AC;
pCodecContext->flags                  |= CODEC_FLAG_LOOP_FILTER | CODEC_FLAG_INTERLACED_ME | CODEC_FLAG_INTERLACED_DCT;
pCodecContext->me_cmp                 |= 1;
pCodecContext->partitions             |= X264_PART_I8X8 | X264_PART_I4X4 | X264_PART_P8X8 | X264_PART_B8X8;
pCodecContext->me_method               = ME_UMH;
pCodecContext->me_subpel_quality       = 8;
pCodecContext->me_range                = 16;

pCodecContext->bit_rate                = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 Mbps??
pCodecContext->width                   = 1920;
pCodecContext->height                  = 1080;

pCodecContext->time_base.num           = 1;    // 25 fps
pCodecContext->time_base.den           = 25;   // 25 fps

pCodecContext->gop_size                = 250; // 250
pCodecContext->keyint_min              = 25;
pCodecContext->scenechange_threshold   = 40;
pCodecContext->i_quant_factor          = 0.71f;
pCodecContext->b_frame_strategy        = 1;
pCodecContext->qcompress               = 0.6f;
pCodecContext->qmin                    = 10;
pCodecContext->qmax                    = 51;
pCodecContext->max_qdiff               = 4;
pCodecContext->max_b_frames            = 3;
pCodecContext->refs                    = 4;
pCodecContext->directpred              = 3;
pCodecContext->trellis                 = 1;
pCodecContext->flags2                 |= CODEC_FLAG2_WPRED | CODEC_FLAG2_MIXED_REFS | CODEC_FLAG2_8X8DCT | CODEC_FLAG2_FASTPSKIP;  // wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8+fastpskip
pCodecContext->weighted_p_pred         = 2; // not implemented with interlaced ??
pCodecContext->crf                     = 22;

pCodecContext->pix_fmt                 = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

pCodecContext->thread_count            = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could analyze some existing 1080i h264 video files to see their parameters.
I found useful for me that links:

- http://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/?p=878
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/h264bitstream/

Answer (score 0):

You should strive to avoid setting any x264 options yourself; the library itself knows best and you'll only get poor tunings from reading old source code. Use the AVOption API to set the "preset"/"tune"/"profile" options on the encoder to what you need (see `x264 --help`).